# Having issue while sending two strings from clent to server in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to send two strings from client to server but only the first string is successfully passed, the second one doesn't seem to work.

> client code

```
char *a[2];
    char temp[100];
    printf("Enter name of file : ");
    scanf("%s", temp);
    a[0] = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1); 
    strcpy(a[0],temp);

    printf("Enter name of operation : ");
    scanf("%s", temp);
    a[1] = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1); 
    strcpy(a[1],temp);

    int i = 0;
    while(i<2)
    {
        send(sock , a[i], sizeof(a[i]), 0 ); 
        i++;
    }
```

> Server code:

```
int i = 0;
    char *buffer[2];
    while (i < 2)
    {
        buffer[i] = malloc(1000);
        int size = read(new_socket, buffer[i], 1000);
        buffer[i][size] = '\0';
        printf("BUFF : %s\n", buffer[i]);
        printf("Size : %d\n", size);
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("%s\n", buffer[1]);
```

> Input:

Enter file name : w

Enter operation code : 1f

> output:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate question. Previous question asked by the same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153147/inconsistent-output-when-im-sending-2-strings-from-client-to-server-in-c#comment108189802_61153147

Comment: I tried to help too. The issue was in server side

Comment: Ok, now you've deleted that previous question. So I repeat: For stream based protocols you cannot assume each `read` will read exactly one message sent by `send`. You need to keep calling `read` until all data is received. In this case, until you see two NUL characters.

Comment: @AbhayAravinda That's was not helpful at all. I know that the issue is on the server side. But I'm not able to rectify it. That's the issue!

Comment: @kaylum So how can I make it work?

Comment: You can't assume that the data from `read` is exactly one string. One way is to read into a temporary buffer. Then parse the buffer copying each byte into the final `buffer[i]` until a NUL character is encountered which indicates the end of a string. Then move to the next `buffer[i]`.

Comment: `scanf("%s", temp)` lacks return value checking and is [weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) code.  Consider `if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin)) { ...`

Comment: Tip: Use sentinels to clearly see the being/end of a print which may have leading/trailing white-space or multiple lines. `printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);` --> `printf("<%s>\n", buffer[i]);`

Comment: `printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
        buffer[i][size] = '\0';` is certainly out of order.  Reverse that.  Perhaps print `size` also.

Comment: "the second one doesn't seem to work." --> That is not so informative.  Post input used, output seen, output expected.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Please have a look now.

Comment: Tips: 1) rather than post picture of text, post text.  2) Post true code//input/output: `Enter operation code : 1f` does not match expectations of `printf("Enter name of operation : ");
    scanf("%s", temp);` and so creates unneeded confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Wrong size**

Code sends using the size of pointer `a[i]` (likely 8) when the length of the string is desired.

```
// send(sock , a[i], sizeof(a[i]), 0 ); 
send(sock , a[i], strlen(s[i]), 0 ); 
// or (see below)
send(sock , a[i], strlen(s[i]) + 1, 0 );
```

**No deliminator**

The receiving end is getting the concatenation of the two `send()`.

Also send the null character, so the receiver could parse input (which might be multiple strings).

or

Code could send the length and the string so the receiver could get the length and then the string,

or

many other ways.  e.g. [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155776/having-issue-while-sending-two-strings-from-clent-to-server-in-c/61156280?noredirect=1#comment108190052_61155776), [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155776/having-issue-while-sending-two-strings-from-clent-to-server-in-c/61156280?noredirect=1#comment108190882_61156280)

Comment: How can I put a delimiter?

Comment: @MUHAMMADQASIMKHAN Example: To send a delimiter, `send(sock , "|", 1, 0 );` .  Receiving code will need to parse the input for it.

Comment: @MUHAMMADQASIMKHAN,As for me, I would send `<`, the string, and `>` and have the receiver use the `<`, `>`  to discern the beginning and end of the text.  Of course, the string should not contain `<`, `>`